# need to solve this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find the name of employees who are working on more than 2 companies from the following 
tables:

```
Employee (employee_name, street, city, age)

Works (employee_name, company_name, salary)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you employee names who are working for more than 2 companies. You can join into the Employee table if you need more of their details.

```
SELECT
 employee_name
FROM
 Works
GROUP BY
 employee_name
HAVING
 COUNT(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT employee_name FROM Works GROUP BY employee_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

This makes a list with each employee represented once, then filters out the employees so that only those with more than two records contributing to the group are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from earlier provided answers (which are correct btw), if you should need to join the tables, consider using numbers as a primary key (I'm assuming the employee_name is the primary key in both tables).

This would speed up your query (provided that you have lots of records in one or both tables), because your DBMS will compare integers instead of strings, which is considerably faster.

Comment: Depends entirely on the indexing scheme used by the database.  Most will use a hash on the name, so not much additional speed there.  You're very unlikely to get back the performance you will lose to the necessity of now maintaining TWO indexes on Employee, one on the ID (for joins) and one on the employee_name (for searches).  In general, it's best to use the correct representation of the data and let the database handle the optimization.  (Employee_name is not a good PK for other reasons, performance is probably not one of them).